# jquery How to post showValues() data to another page

Tags: jquery

I am using this function to show value selected in my form. The result is showing properly on my page but nothing is sent to my getlist.php page.

Can somebody help me please?

Jquery code:

```
function showValues() {
    var str = $("form").serialize();
    $("#results").text(str);
}

$(":checkbox, :radio").click(showValues);
$("select").change(showValues);
showValues();

$.post("getlist.php", $("form").serialize());
```

HTML:

```
<p><tt id="results"></tt></p>
```

here is my form

```
<form id="Moteur" onchange="testMoteur()">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" bgcolor="#Be9e55">
<tr height="30px">
<td align="right">Marques : </td>
<td><? include ("marques.php"); ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and the marques.php code

```
<select name="marques" id="marques" multiple="multiple">
<?
//<option value="x">Toutes les marques :</option>
?>
<?
mysql_connect("","",""); 
mysql_select_db(""); 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marque WHERE flag_montre=1 ORDER BY nom ASC");
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
$id_marque=$myrow[0];
//test si marque est vide
$res3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM montre WHERE id_marque=$id_marque AND id_etat=3");
$nbreLignes = mysql_num_rows($res3);
if ($nbreLignes==0){
}
else {  
echo "<option value='".$myrow[0]."'>".$myrow[1]." (".$nbreLignes.")</option>"; 
} 
} 
                    ?>
</select>
```

I have just updated my script, all is working great on Firefox but nothing happen in ie8 (0 errors). The goal of this script is to send vars in array to my getlist.php

```
function SendMoteur() {

var xmlhttp = "";
var url = "";

// For modern browsers
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

// for IE 5/6
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

//  Rebuild the array of selected option boxes
marques = document.getElementById("marques");
for(var i=0; i < marques.length; i++) {
    if(marques[i].selected) {
        // Note the [] after the name
        url += "&marques[]=" + marques[i].value;
    }
}

 fourchettes = document.getElementById("fourchettes");
for(var i=0; i < fourchettes.length; i++) {
    if(fourchettes[i].selected) {
        // Note the [] after the name
        url += "&fourchettes[]=" + fourchettes[i].value;
    }
}

mouvements = document.getElementById("mouvements");
for(var i=0; i < mouvements.length; i++) {
    if(mouvements[i].selected) {
        // Note the [] after the name
        url += "&mouvements[]=" + mouvements[i].value;
    }
}

boitiers = document.getElementById("boitiers");
for(var i=0; i < boitiers.length; i++) {
    if(boitiers[i].selected) {
        // Note the [] after the name
        url += "&boitiers[]=" + boitiers[i].value;
    }
}

bracelets = document.getElementById("bracelets");
for(var i=0; i < bracelets.length; i++) {
    if(bracelets[i].selected) {
        // Note the [] after the name
        url += "&bracelets[]=" + bracelets[i].value;
    }
}


xmlhttp.open("GET","getlist.php?" + url, false);
xmlhttp.send();

if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
} else {
    return false;
}

return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: show us your HTML(form) codes too..

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct jQuery form, try this:

```
$.post("getlist.php", $("#form").serialize());
```

or if this is a form class try this:

```
$.post("getlist.php", $(".form").serialize());
```

Also, check if the getlist.php file is in the same folder as your current file.

Comment: He said the `showValues()` function works correctly, so it's just `$("form")` - no class or ID.

Comment: All the files are in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use this equavalent one:

give id to your form: `form_id`

```
function showValues() {
 var str = $("#form_id").serialize();
 $("#results").text(str);

 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "getlist.php",
  data: {data: str},
 }).done(function(){
     alert('yiha, worked!');
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but nothing is sent to getlist.php

Comment: I use print_r($_POST); in my getlist.php, perhaps it is not the good way to verify that the serialezed var is sent !